# 7 Segment display loops back to 9

Tags: integrated-circuit, debugging, 7segmentdisplay

[image: 7 Segment Display]

I am trying to figure out why the 7-segment display at the top part loops back to 9 when the timer reaches 0. I want the timer to display 0 whenever it stops. What kind of adjustments should I make to allow for this to happen?

Comment: You need to reset the counters at zero

Comment: You need pulldown resistors for your pushbutton switches.